# Xamarin.Forms Animation on click Button (Flash background)

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, xamarin.forms

I want to implement a dialpad on my form.
Now, in my XAML I am testing a button:
XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
         x:Class="MyXFDemo001.Views.NewItemPage"
         Title="New Item">
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Clicked="Save_Clicked" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        <Button
            x:Name="buttonSelectContact"
            Clicked="buttonSelectContact_Clicked"
            Text="CLICK" BackgroundColor="#0080ff" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And in my code behind I have a method **buttonSelectContact_Clicked**:

```
private async void buttonSelectContact_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    btn.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#22ac38");
    await Task.Delay(500);
    btn.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#0080ff");
}
```

It works, but not quietly as smooth as I want.
Can you suggest me to add animation instead of this BackgroundColor?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58818/how-to-animate-change-of-background-color

Comment: @Johannes thanks, I've already seen this post. Question - on which event should I bind this method "StartAnimation" from accepted answer on this page that you provided me? Also, in my CodeBehind, I can't "see" a label called x:Name ="whiteLabel" ?Thanks

Comment: Call `StartAnimation` from your `buttonSelectContact_Clicked`. You have to add two buttons (to a grid, to overlay them) with two different background colors (one #0080ff, other #22ac38), maybe one without clicked event (depends on how you want the functionality...), and give one x:Name="buttonSelectContactStandardColor" and the other x:Name="buttonSelectContactAnimationColor", then call `FadeTo` on the one that is shown normally...

Comment: @Johannes I understand what you said. If you want to answer on my question with sample code, that I can accept your answer?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out :) @Stefan0309

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/58818/how-to-animate-change-of-background-color
your code would look like this

XAML

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
    <Grid>
        <Button
        x:Name="buttonSelectContactSecond"
        Text="CLICK" BackgroundColor="#22ac38" />
        <Button
            x:Name="buttonSelectContact"
            Clicked="buttonSelectContact_Clicked"
            Text="CLICK" BackgroundColor="#0080ff" />
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

In code behind

```
private async void buttonSelectContact_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    StartAnimation();
}

private async void StartAnimation()
{
    await Task.Delay(200);
    await buttonSelectContact.FadeTo(0, 250);
    await Task.Delay(200);
    await buttonSelectContact.FadeTo(1, 250);
}
```

Answer (score 28):

I guess the better choice is to create a reusable feature to do that. You may take advantage of the animation resources from [xamarin.forms](/questions/tagged/xamarin.forms).

For example, you can create an extension method that provides you a nice and easy way to reuse anywhere, like `FadeTo` or `TranslateTo`...

It is pretty easy, except for the logic that smoothly changes the color in this particular case. Here is the code:

```
public static class AnimationExtensions
{
    public static Task<bool> ChangeBackgroundColorTo(this Button self, Color newColor, uint length = 250, Easing easing = null)
    {
        Task<bool> ret = new Task<bool>(() => false);

        if (!self.AnimationIsRunning(nameof(ChangeBackgroundColorTo)))
        {
            Color fromColor = self.BackgroundColor;

            try
            {
                Func<double, Color> transform = (t) =>
                  Color.FromRgba(fromColor.R + t * (newColor.R - fromColor.R),
                                 fromColor.G + t * (newColor.G - fromColor.G),
                                 fromColor.B + t * (newColor.B - fromColor.B),
                                 fromColor.A + t * (newColor.A - fromColor.A));

                ret = TransmuteColorAnimation(self, nameof(ChangeBackgroundColorTo), transform, length, easing);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // to supress animation overlapping errors 
                self.BackgroundColor = fromColor;
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }

    private static Task<bool> TransmuteColorAnimation(Button button, string name, Func<double, Color> transform, uint length, Easing easing)
    {
        easing = easing ?? Easing.Linear;
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

        button.Animate(name, transform, (color) => { button.BackgroundColor = color; }, 16, length, easing, (v, c) => taskCompletionSource.SetResult(c));
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
```

Importing this class (by the `using namespace` reference) you will be able to use it like bellow.

Declaring an `XAML` button:

```
<Button Text="Nice button ;)"
        BackgroundColor="Gray"
        x:Name="btnTeste"
        Clicked="btnTest_Click"/>
```

Handling click in the code-behind:

```
private async void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    #region You will not need this block, it is just to choose a random color for change to
    var colors = new[] { Color.Red, Color.Pink, Color.Silver, Color.Yellow, Color.Black, Color.Green };
    var rnd = new Random();

    var actualColor = btnTeste.BackgroundColor;
    var randomColor = colors.Where(c => c != actualColor).ToArray()[rnd.Next(0, colors.Length - 2)];
    #endregion

    // Here is the effective use of the smooth background color change animation
    await btnTeste.ChangeBackgroundColorTo(randomColor, 150, Easing.CubicOut);
    await btnTeste.ChangeBackgroundColorTo(actualColor, 100, Easing.SinOut);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the result (the gif shows clicks and double-clicks, so you can see a lot of smoothy changes):

[image: effect example]

Comment: Awesome! I like this approach

Comment: Great solution, this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: Beautifully done, my friend! And simpler, no custom renderers!

Answer (score 5):

You can also create the universal custom control with animation:

In this sample, I used Image control, but you can use Button, Label, etc. :)

```
public class NativeImage : Image
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Command),
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(NativeImage),
            default(ICommand));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get => (ICommand) GetValue(CommandProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(Command),
            typeof(object),
            typeof(NativeImage));

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get => GetValue(CommandParameterProperty);
        set => SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value);
    }

    private ICommand TransitionCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                AnchorX = 0.48;
                AnchorY = 0.48;
                await this.ScaleTo(0.8, 50, Easing.Linear);
                await Task.Delay(100);
                await this.ScaleTo(1, 50, Easing.Linear);
                Command?.Execute(CommandParameter);
            });
        }
    }

    public NativeImage()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer
        {
            Command = TransitionCommand
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In general this is a good idea, but for this specific example, you need two buttons/labels/whatever one above the other and only one should have the animation of fading out to achieve a blinking effect of the background.  You have to understand, that FadeTo is just a fading animation of the opaque value, so you just hide the button slowly and then let it appear again.

I don't know if it its possible with custom renderers, but this could maybe the best approach for something like that...