# How to animate colors in .net maui?

Tags: c#, maui

How to correctly animate colors? I am trying to animate ***Button.BackgroundColor*** with ***Animation*** class, but when I press the button, the color immediately turns white, bypassing the intermediate states. Why is this happening?

```
namespace BucketList
{
    class ButtonAnimation : TriggerAction<Button>
    {
        protected override async void Invoke(Button sender)
        {
            var animation = new Animation()
            {
                { 0, 1, new Animation((x) => sender.FontSize = x, 20, 32) },
                { 0, 1, new Animation((x) => sender.Rotation = x, 0, 360, easing: Easing.SpringIn) },
                { 0, 1, new Animation((x) => sender.BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgb(x, x, x), 0, 255) }
            };

            animation.Commit(sender, "ComplexAnimation", length: 2500, repeat: () => true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the initial value of `BackgroundColor` of the `Button` and then set it to another value in TriggerAction during animation.

The below example shows how to animate the `BackgroundColor` from `Colors.Red` to `Colors.AliceBlue`:

**XAML:**

```
<Button Text="click me" 
         BackgroundColor="Red"
         TextColor="White">
         <Button.Triggers>
               <EventTrigger Event="Clicked">
                     <local:ButtonAnimation/>
               </EventTrigger>
          </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

**Code-behind:**

```
protected override void Invoke(Button sender)
{

           var animation = new Animation()

            {

                { 0, 1, new Animation((x) => sender.FontSize = x, 20, 32) },

                { 0, 1, new Animation((x) => sender.Rotation = x, 0, 360, easing: Easing.SinOut) },

                { 0, 1, new Animation((x) => sender.BackgroundColor = Colors.White,0,0) }

            };

            await Task.Delay(700);

            animation.Commit(sender, "ComplexAnimation", length: 5000, repeat: () => true);


}
```

Comment: This implementation changes the color instantly, while I want to achieve a smooth transition between colors

Comment: Thanks for your update, to make it smooth, you may set the length longer to `5000` and add `await Task.Delay(700);` before animate. I have updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem. I need the color to change shades during the transition to another as it was in WPF

Comment: @luvairo You may refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50425594/9644964, it has the shades during transition!

Comment: Or you can use [ColorAnimationExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/extensions/color-animation-extensions) as The `ColorAnimationExtensions` provide a series of extension methods that support animating the **Color**. And by setting `length`, of type uint, is the duration, in milliseconds, of the animation. This is an optional argument, whose default value is 250. You can set it longer which will lead to a smooth transition.