# How to use Xamarin/MAUI AnimationIsRunning() method?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

What is the string handle that is supposed to be passed in for `AnimationIsRunning()`?
I have a scroll animation that I run programmatically:

```
public void ScrollToBookPage(object item, ScrollToPosition position, bool animated)
{
    /** - Select book page */
    lvBookPages.ScrollTo(item, position, animated);
}
```

And then in some other method, I check if the animation is running:

```
public void IsPageScrollRunning(string handle)
{
    /** - Is page scrolling? */
    lvBookPages.AnimationIsRunning(handle);
}
```

But, I don't know what the string handle is supposed to be!

`lvBookPages` is a ListView, to clarify.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.animationextensions.animationisrunning?view=net-maui-7.0

I read the docs, but they didn't seem to clear things up very much.
And, I couldn't find any examples by googling.

Comment: Understand it like a GUID for the animation. The method pretty much works like that: I told you to rotate a while a go. Did you finish with that exact rotation?

Comment: I think I confused you even more, I think it is best to read here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/animation/custom?view=net-maui-7.0 Notice how they call abort, by name.

Comment: Normally, you use` if (this.AnimationIsRunning("TranslationAnimation")){ return; }` to judge if the animation is running and then define your own animation and then commit it like `translation.Commit(this, "TranslationAnimation", length: 100);`, you can refer to [MainPage.cs](https://github.com/memsranga/Balloony/blob/6f7a963585bb69eb2e68e0525ed53c4c42472b74/Balloony/MainPage.xaml.cs). Or you use ` if (!self.AnimationIsRunning("AnimationName"))` to judge if the animation is not running,perform the animation, you can refer to [custom animation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50425594/9644964).

Comment: Thank you guys for the info and examples! I really appreciate it. While I was waiting I was using focus states to determine if the animation was running or not. When I get some more time I will try the custom animations you guys have described. Thank you for contributing to the knowledge pool on this topic!

Comment: @MerricWanderer My pleasure! If you need any other help, please don't hesitate to reach out to me.